# WordPress $wpdb->get_results show all the rows in a table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In WordPress, I have a table called `wp_users`
and I want to show all of them in a custom html table. So, my query goes like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>Last Name</td>
      <td> Email </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_users");
    foreach ( $rows as $row ) ?>
      <tr>
        <td>echo $row->first_name;</td>
        <td>echo $row->first_name;</td>
        <td> echo $row->first_name;</td>
      </tr>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
```

This one is giving result for all the first_name inside the first table like this

```
<tr>
  <td>Test 1Test 2</td>
  <td>Test 12Test 2</td>
  <td> test@test.comtest2@test.com</td>
</tr>
```

but I want the result be like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td> Email </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    <td>Test 12</td>
    <td> test@test.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    <td> test2@test.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So, Can someone tell me how to do this?
Any help and suggestions wll be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: echo out the table tags outside the loop and build the table rows inside the loop.

Comment: How is it fetching first_name? According to the codex there's no such field? http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_users

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple you just have to give the correct columnname inside foreach loop.
Right now you are just trying to print the firstname. And there is a bracket"{" missing after the foreach loop

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td> Email </td>           
   </tr>
  <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_users");
    foreach ( $rows as $row ) 
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td>echo $row->first_name;</td>
      <td>echo $row->Lastname;</td>
      <td> echo $row->Email;</td>           
   </tr>

   <?php }
  ?>
```